# Converting a number in Scientific Notation to Double Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, scientific-notation

Jackson version : 2.0.2

```
 String jsonString = "{\"data\":10000000.00, \"data2\" : 0E-7}";
 ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
 JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
 System.out.println(jsonNode.toString());
 System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString));
```

I’m getting the following response

```
{"data":10000000.00,"data2":0E-7}
{"data":1.0E7,"data2":0.0}
```

Is there anything I could do to get the output
{"data":10000000.00,"data2”:0.0}

Comment: After one gets the BigDecimal `data` you might do `if (data.scale() < 0) data = data.setScale(0);`. The same on the creation side; or maybe you can use `data.toPlainString()` on creation.

Comment: There will be lot of nodes like data. I can't check each and every node like this. Also I don't know what are the nodes that would have its value as a double.